Is there a difference between using `this.property` or `Object(property: ...)` for setting class attributes?
Say I have the following constructor for the class MyClass:
    public MyClass(int my_property) {
        Object(my_property: my_property);
    }

and then this constructor, which should be equivalent according to this guide:
    public MyClass(int my_property) {
        this.my_property = my_property;
    }

I want to know if there's something different going on under the hood. Also, where should I choose each of these over the other? I've seen the former used in most scenarios.

this.property:Used to assign a value to a class attribute within the constructor of the class itself.
Object(property: ...): Creates a new object with the specified properties. It's not typically used for setting class attributes.
this.property: The property becomes a member of the class instance (this).
Object(property: ...): The property belongs to the newly created object, which is likely not what you intend for class attributes.

So, considering that the constructor's main job is to create a new object of type MyClass with the specified properties, is there a difference between the behavior of the two snippets? @KrishnaKanth
edit: I just saw the second part of your comment. Thanks!

this.property: integrates the property into the MyClass instance where as Object(property: ...): creates an unrelated object.

Okay if that's the case then I don't understand why anyone would use Object() in the constructor. Say in this source code file or this one @KrishnaKanth

The code does the same, if the attribute is marked as "construct" or "set". If it is marked as construct only, the attribute can then only be set via the Object() call in the constructor and not modified later.
Here is an example:
public class ClassA : Object
{
  public int value_a {get; construct;}
  public int value_b {get; set;}
  public int value_c;

  public ClassA()
  {
    Object(
      value_a: 23, // <- allowed
      value_b: 23, // <- allowed
      value_c: 23  // <- not allowed
    );

    this.value_a = 23; // <- not allowed
    this.value_b = 23; // <- allowed
    this.value_c = 23; // <- allowed
  }

  public void modify()
  {
    this.value_a = 42; // <- not allowed!
    this.value_b = 42; // <- allowed!
    this.value_c = 42; // <- allowed!
  }
}

Under the hood your example compiles to c code like this:
self = g_object_new(object_type, "my-property", my_property, NULL);

And:
self = g_object_new(object_type, NULL);
my_class_set_my_property(self, my_property);

